# How can I get the previous Value of the TextView F12

Tags: java, android

How can I get the previous Value of the TextView F12? I want to put a Value in F12 and in a second Part, I want to add the previous Value with a new Value.

```
final String numbers = bundle.getString("numbers");         
int F12Total = 0;
F12.setText(String.valueOf(numbers));

    if (numbers != null){

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers.toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(F12.getText().toString());
        F12Total = num1 + num2;
        F12.setText(String.valueOf(F12Total));
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you give more info about the context of the code and functionality purpose?  What have you tried and did not work?

Comment: I want to fill the first Value of numbers with (for example) "35" and the second Value of numbers with "5" (In a second Part). Then the Value of F12Total is "40".

Answer (score 1):

Create a String to use to temporarily store the value from F12 like so:

```
String valueOfF12 = F12.getText().toString();
```

and then refer back to that string when you need to retrieve that information later.

Answer (score 0):

Store your `TextView` `F12` value into a temporary  `tempF12`  variable and use later.

**Try this:**

```
// Global
String tempF12 = "0";

...........
.................

final String numbers = bundle.getString("numbers");         

int F12Total = 0;
F12.setText(String.valueOf(numbers));

if (numbers != null) {

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers.toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(tempF12);

    F12Total = num1 + num2;
    F12.setText(String.valueOf(F12Total));
}

// Store current F12 value to use later
tempF12 = F12.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but when I fill the Value of "numbers" with (for example) "35" and in a second Part with "5", then is F12Total = "5".  I cant save the first Value and the second Value of F12Total in a String?

Comment: Sorry, the first Value and the second Value of "numbers".